# How to override (not patch) a single method in a python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, overriding

I've searched for hours. Can't find anyone even trying to do this. Hmmm.

I believe I have to override a single method within a class instance. I do **not** mean `patch(return_value=)`. I need to make the method in question do something involving `self`.

I'll try to break it down. Liberally paraphrasing and including one of the many things I tried, which doesn't work  ...

```py
class SetupClass(object):
    def set_some_stuff(self):
        data_list = functon_cannot_be_run_on_test_platform()
        self.something = data_list[0]
        self.something_else = data_list[1]

class UUT(object):
    self.config = SetupClass()
    assert self.config.something == 'foo'

class UnitTests(TestCase):

    @patch('SetupClass')
    def test_UUT(self, mock1):

        def WedgeClass(SetupClass):
            def set_some_stuff(self):
                self.something = 'foo'
                pass # I'm a Python newbie, in too deep

        wedge_class = WedgeClass()
        mock1.return_value = wedge_class # doesn't work. context errors

        uut = UUT() # <-- would crash here, because assert above
```

Assume that I cannot make changes to `UUT` or `SetupClass`.

Testing cannot even get off the ground because the assertion will fail, due to, `SetupClass.functon_cannot_be_run_on_test_platform()`. **Note that** simply mocking `SetupClass.functon_cannot_be_run_on_test_platform` will not solve the problem, because reasons.

ATM, I figure the only way to get around this mess is to somehow override `SetupClass.set_some_stuff`. I cannot simply mock the entire class, because `UUT` relies heavily on its other functionality as well. I need everything to work as is, except this one method *and* I need that method to be able to access, `self` in the same context as originally intend.

I tried various things involving subclassing and mock.return_value etc. I'd rather not recall the pain that caused. :p

My kingdom for test-driven code in the first place! This code contains a convolution of co-dependencies. :-/

Comment: `class` has to be started with `class UUT`, not `def UUT` and ident is off

Comment: @Gang ... oh yeah. Just typos. I've already edited the pseudo code a dozen times. Sorry. Current version is closer to what I've actually tried.

Comment: `def WedgeClass` should be outside of `class UnitTests`? 2 lines in `class UUT` in a function `__init__()` or other functions?

Comment: @Gang ... yeah, syntax is still obviously wrong, at least, dangit. I'm back a  real computer now, so I'll test the actual code and sort it out. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the multiple errors in the example code I wrote up off the top of my head at the cafe ...

The problem was (mostly) that I was using `return_value` instead of `side_effect` to 'replace' the patched class with my own subclass.

My need, re-stated perhaps more clearly now, is to override a single method, `set_some_stuff`, in a class within the unit under test (UUT) but without mocking the class.

The method issues several 'self.foo = bar' statements, which I want to change for testing purposes. Thus, mocking the method's (unused) return value is not enough ... and patch.object seems to lose class context, "'self' unknown" or the like.

**Finally**, here is the working code, doing what I need ...

```py
import unittest
import mock

class SetupClass(object):
    def set_some_stuff(self):
        data_list = ['data not available', 'on test_platform'] # CRASH!
        self.something = data_list[0]
        self.something_else = data_list[1]

class UUT:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = SetupClass()
        self.config.set_some_stuff()
        assert self.config.something == 'foo' # <-- used to crash before here ...
        self.got_here = True # ... but now the override method from
                             # WedgeClass is being used! :=)

"""
Subclass the original class, overriding just the method in question.  Then set
the subclass as the side_effect of the patched original, effectively replacing it.
"""
class WedgeClass(SetupClass):
    def set_some_stuff(self):
        self.something = 'foo'
        pass # I'm a Python newbie, in too deep

class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch(__module__+'.SetupClass')
    def test_UUT(self, mock1):
        wedge_class = WedgeClass()
        mock1.side_effect = WedgeClass # <--- Ureka! 'side_effect' not 'return_value' was the ley!

        uut = UUT()
        self.assertTrue(uut.got_here)
```